# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

```
geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                List<Address> addressList = null;

               try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(firstLocationLattiutde, firstLocationlongitude, 5);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Address obj = addressList.get(0);
                add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
                guardAddress.setText(add);
```

but sometime it give error like this

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference at com.example.fahadaziz.securityapplication.Services.MyService.onLocationChanged

Comment: addressList is null, geocoder.getFromLocation(); is not returning data

Answer (score 1):

`geocoder.getFromLocation()` method is returning `null`. 
So before performing any operation on `addresslist` you must check for `null`.

```
if(addresslist != null)
{
    //go ahead
}
```